# Applying a TRUNC() function to a range in COUNTIFS(). Or using SUMPRODUCT() instead?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a column (Col C) of decimal numbers. I'm trying to count how many of the entries in Col C are equal to 13 if truncated while Col B = "USA". Is it possible to apply a function to a range like this?

I've seen this question asked in different contexts and the suggestions have been to use SUMPRODUCT() somehow instead.

Here are some examples of what I've been trying:

```
=COUNTIFS(TRUNC(Data!C:C,0),13,Data!B:B,"USA")
=COUNTIFS(Data!C:C,TRUNC(Data!C:C,0)=13,Data!B:B,"USA")
=SUMPRODUCT(TRUNC(Data!C:C,0)=13, Data!B:B="USA")
```

The SUMPRODUCT() just returns #VALUE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just expand the COUNTIFS?

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!C:C,">=13",Data!C:C,"<14",Data!B:B,"USA")
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't click that I could check the same range twice.

Answer (score 1):

The COUNTIFS() by @tigeravatar would be the best solution.

To why your SUMPRODUCT() did not work:

When using the Boolean as a counting mechanism in SUMPRODUCT one need to reduce them to the bit equivalent.  This is done with any mathematical process.

I prefer to multiply the two together:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INT(Data!C1:C100)=13)*(Data!B1:B100="USA"))
```

When using SUMPRODUCT, which is an array type formula, one should limit the range to the actual dataset and not use full column references.